# PhD supervision numbers by discipline

Tags: career-path

My faculty imposes some numerical "recommendations" for promotions. Instead of arguing this sort of recommendation is ridiculous, I think it is wiser to provide some evidence the recommended numbers are far too high for (pure) mathematics.

Is there data available for the average or mean number of PhD completions when applying for Associate Professor and Professor in the at e.g. R1 universities in the USA, or for any other country, for mathematics and ideally for other scientific disciplines as well.

Comment: Shouldn't the local numbers be more relevant here? What is typical historically at your place? You can probably do the stats yourself.

Comment: Depending on their goals, I'd caution you that this may be very unlikely to be persuasive. For example, if they want to promote faculty based on likelihood to mentor graduate students, arguing that your field doesn't mentor many graduate students at all would be counter to your goals.

Comment: That data is not available, to my knowledge. However, ask a librarian at your uni. They are great with identifying data sources.

Comment: local numbers are not a good measure of arguing that their standards are not appropriate as the response will be well maybe your dept is underperforming, in fact the best witness of inappropriate standards is that people who got Professor title sometimes a decade or two ago would have to be demoted based on these new "standards". Luckily a group of them have now taken action to try and fix these quantitative incentives which lead to low level publications and poor supervision.